# Why is the request body empty and the responce status is 404?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to build a web application using MVC pattern, but I have a problem with POST-request to "http://localhost:5000/api/device": [postman POST request attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJhS0.png)

The problem only occurs on POST request, GET request is OK: [get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRSow.png)

**Code:**

*index.js*

```
const express = require('express')
const sequelize = require('./db')
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path')

const models = require('./models/models')
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express();
const router = require('./routes/index')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

const errorHandler = require('./milddleware/ErrorHandlingMiddleware')
app.use(cors())

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'static')))

app.use(fileUpload({}))

app.use('/api', router)

app.use(errorHandler)
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const db_start = async ()=>
{
    try
    {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        await sequelize.sync();
        app.listen(PORT, ()=>{console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`)})
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

db_start()
```

*routes/index.js*

```
const  Router  = require('express')

const router = new Router();

const deviceRouter = require('./deviceRouter')
const typeRouter = require('./typeRouter')
const brandRouter = require('./brandRouter')
const userRouter = require('./userRouter')

router.use('/user', userRouter)
router.use('/device', deviceRouter)
router.use('/brand', brandRouter)
router.use('/type', typeRouter)

module.exports = router
```

*routes/deviceRouter.js*

```
const  Router  = require('express')
const DeviceController = require('../controllers/deviceController')

const router = new Router();

router.post('/', DeviceController.create)
router.get('/', DeviceController.getAll)
router.get('/:id', DeviceController.getOne)
module.exports = router
```

*controllers\deviceController.js*

```
const uuid = require('uuid')
const path = require('path')
const {Device} = require('../models/models')
const ApiError = require("../errors/ApiError")

class DeviceController
{
    async create(req, res, next)
    {
        console.log(req);
      try{  
        const {name, price, brandId, typeId, info} = req.body;
        const {img} = req.files;
        let fileName = uuid.v4() + ".jpg";
        img.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', fileName));
        
        const device = await Device.create({name, price, brandId, typeId, img: fileName});
        return res.json(device);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            next(ApiError.badRequest(e.message));
        }

    }

    async getAll(req, res)
    {
        const {brandId, typeId} = req.query
        let devices;
        if(!brandId && !typeId)
        {
            devices = await Device.findAll()
        }
        if(brandId && !typeId)
        {
            devices = await Device.findAll({where: {brandId}})

        }
        if(!brandId && typeId)
        {
            devices = await Device.findAll({where: {typeId}})
        }
        if(brandId && typeId)
        {
            devices = await Device.findAll({where: {brandId,typeId}})
        }
        return res.json(devices)
            
    }

    async getOne(req,res)
    {
        
    }
}

module.exports = new DeviceController()
```

I logged the request and saw that the request body came up empty and `req.files` is undefined.
I compared these router and controller with others and found no differences in structure.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve files of `form-data` directly from `req.files`.

Use `formidable` (it's an npm package) to `parse form-data` and work with it easily. Here are the steps:

1. Run `npm install formidable`.
2. Import `formidable` and `fs` package in your controller script with:

   ```
   const formidable = require('formidable')
   const fs = require('fs');
   ```
3. Change your `create function` with this:

   ```
   async create(req, res, next) {
       let form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
       form.keepExtensions = true

       form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
           // console.log('err', err)
           // console.log('fields', fields)

           if (err) {
               next(ApiError.badRequest(err));
               return;
           }

           const { name, price, brandId, typeId, info } = fields; // <-- fields contain all your text data. it's like req.body
           const { img } = files; // <-- it should work now!
           let fileName = uuid.v4() + ".jpg";
           fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', fileName), img);

           const device = await Device.create({ name, price, brandId, typeId, img: fileName });
           return res.json(device);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I got this: https://prnt.sc/1sb4a2x and my request in postman freezes.

Comment: I've updated my code. have a look. follow all steps again.